# Compartilhar bibliotecas de código entre aplicações

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

No meu cenário tenho várias aplicações distintas (desktop) que são criadas das mais diversas formas, em suma, podem ser agrupadas naquelas que utilizam a mesma DLL. O funcionamento de cada aplicação depende que o as toda a aplicação seja instalada, junto com as DLLs, o que causa repetição desses arquivos na máquina do usuário. Tratando-se de bibliotecas proprietárias, não padrões do Windows, existe alguma forma de torná-las acessíveis para todas as aplicações com um só arquivo? Tendo em vista que não está ao meu alcance mudar diretamente no código o relacionamento do programa com a biblioteca.

Comment: prefiro manter as duplicações, apesar de ser "a mesma biblioteca" podem haver versões diferentes... pra evitar que falte alguma, no inicio da aplicação verifico a existência e faço download se necessário. Dessa forma, o usuário só precisa receber o .exe, que ele se encarrega de receber todas as dependências

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que esteja usando o .NET Framework então é só [colocar essas DLLs no GAC (Global Assembly Cache)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/yf1d93sz(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). No .NET Core é bem diferente, e que é o jeito moderno de se programar em C#.

O GAC é o local onde ficam todas DLLs necessárias para a máquina toda e não exclusivas de uma aplicação. Tem que tomar um pouco de cuidado para fazer isso, tem que pensar como vai administrar isso porque pode começar dar problemas nas atualizações, um dos motivos que acabaram com isso no .NET Core. Por isso em muitos casos compensa ter a duplicação e não usar GAC.